# Visual Studio 2008 CSS Validation Level

Tags: css, validation, visual-studio-2008, preferences

I'm validating my CSS at level 2.1 in Visual Studio 08.

Is there a way to change the level you validate to? I can't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up a stylesheet and choose the validation from the drop down menu that appears on the stylesheet menu.

I was looking in tools options..

Answer (score 4):

You can also set the validation options in **Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Validation**